# What do you do when you need to modify a file outside of the TFS branch?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

In TFS, a branch is either a file or a folder. Let's assume I have a folder branched. What if during development, I realize I need to modify a file that isn't in the current branche's scope? (I.e., in a folder higher in the file hierarchy or a sibling folder.)

Example situation: I branch the folder `FinanceProject2018`, which is in the folder `FinanceProjects`. I then realize I need to modify a file in another project, project `FinanceSharedAssets`, also inside the project's parent folder.

Is there a way to merge this additional file to the branch? Or do I need to merge and delete the entire branch, then start again from a higher folder in the hierarchy?

Comment: Not very clear for the hierarchy. What's the impact? You can modify the file and check in the changes to it's branch. You'd better clarify the hierarchy, or capture and share the screenshot here...

Comment: Oh I don't have a specific work case; I made up the example. I just want to know how to handle the situation if it arises.